# Is this grammatical? "Each method has features in which context to use it."

Tags: grammaticality

Is this a grammatically correct sentence?

> "Programming language has a four methods. Each method has features in which context to use it."

Comment: Could you give us some context, please? It's hard to tell what you're trying to say. Are you saying 'Each method had an appropriate context'

Comment: @Pureferret "Programming language has a four methods.Each method has  features in which context to use it."

Comment: @Oyeme: You can edit the question to include this important point: 'Programming ... methods'. Plus, try to break the sentence 'Each... use it.' into two. Then we can understand what you really mean to say.

Comment: I disagree. This is spang **on** topic. Questions like how English questions are formed with modal verbs, and topics like [Negative Polarity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), are **certainly** matters that "relate to English language and usage".

Comment: @John: except that there is no question about modal verbs or negative polarity here. There's only an "is this correct?" — which is, and has always been, off-topic as per the FAQ. Of course this question is related to English! *Every* question asked in English is related to English. But not every question is related to English **within the scope defined in the FAQ**, which is what the close reason actually says. If you wanted to save the question, you should have edited it into shape. In its current form, it will stay closed and then get deleted. We do not do proofreading here. Simple as that.

Comment: OK. Thanks. And a few more characters so I can post it.

Comment: Please never just ask “Is this correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not grammatical. The antecedent of *which* seems to be *features*. If we separate the sentence into two clauses, we get *Each method has features. In those features context to use it.* That clearly makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Something isn't sitting right with me on this sentence.

> "Programming language has a four methods. Each method has features in which context to use it."

I'd replace the second sentence ([subordinate clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subordinate_clause) which doesn't make sense when separated) with something slightly different. Perhaps *...has features, each with different contexts in which they are used*.

In short, no it's not grammatically correct and needs recasting.

Answer (score 3):

> *Each method has features in which context to use it.*

No, it's **not** grammatical. Nor does it make any sense. It's a garden path ending in a trackless maze. The way to tell this is to try to unwind all the rules that have been applied to fold the sentence into this shape and see where it comes from.

The first four words cause no problems, but *in which context to use it* is a horrifically complex and ill-constructed constituent. Technically, it's what's called a ***Relative Infinitive***, and it's been further modified by having a relative pro-adjective *which* modifying another noun *context*, which is the object of a preposition *in*.

And that whole preposition phrase has been ***Pied-Piped*** to the beginning of the infinitive, which lacks a subject, so one needs to be determined, in order to understand the sentence, along with an antecedent for *which*, and a coreferent for *it*, the direct object of *use*.

In other words, something like the skeleton of the relative clause might be represented as

> ... features, such that [someone] uses ***it*** in ***which*** contexts

The [someone] is just an ordinary indefinite, no problem with an infinitive. However, what's *it*? -- it's singular, so it can't be *features*. Then does *which* refer to *features*? And what the hell is *contexts* doing there? You can't **say** **in features contexts*. You can't even say **in feature contexts* and expect it to mean anything here.

I could speculate about where this all came from, given the sentential context, but this seems clear enough. Or unclear enough.

Comment: +1 because it really doesn't make any sense. But I've racked my brain trying to figure out exactly what OP might actually be trying to say. My guess (which to be honest is no more than that) is *Each method has [particular] features governing the contexts in which it can best be used*. As to OP's first sentence, I have no idea whether he means *The* particular programming language he's writing about, or *all* such languages.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently, it is. However, being technically correct is not sufficient. It fails to convey any idea clearly. I can say I get your point, just because I am in the field and can understand the context. (i.e., I know what you mean.) You cannot assume the same with the typical reader.

Overall, it looks incongruous and needs rephrasing.

Comment: -1: I can't see any way to parse either sentence in such a way that I can see them as grammatical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Did I say 'it is'? My point was that being grammatically correct is secondary to being semantically effective. Also, the other down voter, Sir!

Comment: But it *isn't* grammatically correct. Well, *they aren't*, since OP wrote two sentences, neither of which is grammatical. And per my comment to @John's answer, I think I can figure out what the second one was supposed to mean, but I can't be sure about the first.