# What's usage of 'to' following 'which' in a relative clause?

Tags: clauses, relative-clauses

I see a sentence in a commercial article

> Then in 2006, Amazon launched its Elastic Compute cloud (EC2) as a
>   commercial web service that allows small companies and individuals to
>   rent computers on which **to** run their own computer applications.

I could not figure out the usage of 'to' in the relative clause. Is it wrong or some grammatical rule?

Comment: I think this is General Reference for ELU. You might want to look at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No it's not. Where does one look up Relative Infinitives in General Reference or ELL? This is a very complex construction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why is that clause not finite, and why doesn't it have a subject? I don't understand ... why anyone would think that's not a question worth answering or reading about ...?

Comment: @Araucaria: I can hardly disagree with John that a formal deconstruction of what's going on in such usages is "very complex". I was mainly responding to OP's "Is it wrong?", on the grounds that all native speakers know perfectly well they need ***to*** in constructions like *"I bought a diary in which **to** record my daily activity"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I agree they do. The question I suppose, which I find interesting is *why* do they...? :)

Comment: @Araucaria: I can follow John's description of, say, [*Pied-Piping*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/2637) *while I'm reading it* - and as with most such explanations from the professionals, I invariably find the examples both interesting and enlightening. But whereas the answer to OP's *"Is it wrong?"* seems trivial to me as a native speaker, John's answer to *"What's **really** going on? Is there a grammatical rule?"* gets difficult for me because it relies on references to deeper processes that are at best "hazy" to me even immediately after reading about them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not about "*to* following *which* in a relative clause"; grammar is not strings of words.

This is about a different type of Relative clause, a [Relative **Infinitive** clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/54858/15299).
The *to* is the infinitive verbal complementizer (*for* is the subject marker, but there's no subject here), marking the infinitive verb phrase *run their own computer applications*.

A regular relative clause NP with the same meaning as
*computers on which to run their own computer applications* is
*computers on which they can run their own computer applications.*

Both of these relative clauses have undergone [Pied-Piping](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/15299) of the *of* with its object *which*;
however, it's much more common to strand the *of* at the end of the clause. If we don't pied-pipe
the preposition, we can just move the relative pronoun to the front and strand the preposition.
 Watch what happens when we do that:

- *computers **on which** they can run their own computer applications*
  -- with a regular relative clause -- becomes
  *computers **which** they can run their own computer applications **on***
  with *which*, or
  *computers **that** they can run their own computer applications **on***
  with *that*, or just
  *computers they can run their own computer applications **on***
  without any relative pronoun at all.

However,

- *computers **on which** to run their own computer applications*
  -- with a relative infinitive clause -- becomes
  *computers to run their own computer applications **on***
  but **not**
  **computers **which** to run their own computer applications **on***
  and **not**
  **computers **that** to run their own computer applications **on***
  either.

In general, relative infinitives **only** use relative pronouns when they are pied-piped with a preposition; in any other situation, relative pronouns of any kind are forbidden.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation! The rules are much clearer to me now!

Answer (score 0):

It means the purpose of companies is to run their own computer applications **on these computers.** It indicates a purpose.

Comment: Then, can I rewrite it as " rent computers to run their own computer applications", without relative clause?

Comment: You can. Hovewer your sentence doesn't indicate that the applications run **on** these computers.

Comment: @zx_wing but you need *on*. There's a gap at the end of that infinitive construction. It means: ***rent computers [which] to run their own computer applications on*** *[them]*. You can leave out the relative pronoun '*which*' because it's not the subject of the verb '*rent*'.