# use of an infinitive immediately after a relative pronoun with a preposition

Tags: prepositions, relative-pronouns

I was wondering if someone could please help me confirm whether or not, after a relative pronoun preceded by a preposition, you can follow up with an infinitive immediately afterwards or if you have to construct a sentence segment featuring a fresh subject (and possibly auxiliary verb). Naturally, I have examples to clarify this query:

Is this possible:

> This will be a good vantage point from which **to** rain fire down upon the enemy.

Or does it have to be phrased like this:

> This will be a good vantage point, from which **we can** rain fire down upon the enemy?

The first of the two feels possibly correct, but I am not certain if it is strictly so.

Comment: Both are grammatical, if somewhat wordy. The first one is a [relative infinitive construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54858/15299), which allows [Pied-Piping](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/15299), and requires a _Wh_-word in that case; otherwise _Wh_-words are forbidden in relative infinitives: _the book to look in ~ the book in which to look_ ~ *_the book which to look in_. The second sentence is a normal (not infinitive) relative clause, also with Pied-Piping. Both types are restrictive relatives, so there should be no comma in the second sentence.